# Dynamically load content every 5 secs

Tags: ajax, wordpress, performance, caching

I'm working on Worpress site where is ajax functionality which cause me some worries. Idea is that with **ajax we fetch post** (just title and one metakey) **every 5-10 seconds** (automaticaclly every 10secs and if user hits refresh button on site then immidiately). There might be few hundreds users at same time on the site after publishing newsletter. Other times there's probably only some tens simultenoius users. So the worry is that maybe it cause some **performance issues on my webhotel**? Could this fetch done other better way?

Ajax part:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://myadmin.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        'action': 'get_stuff',
        'fn': 'get_post_info'
    },
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success:function(data){     
        // do some append to show it for usrs

    },
    error: function(errorThrown){
        // error case
    }
});
```

There's new content/posts every day 10-50 which should be showed there too.

Thank you for all your help!

EDIT: What if I get all posts in one request as js array and then just show stuff from the array every 10secs. That way I could avoid this problem?

Comment: Maybe you can use APC, memcache or another caching method?

Comment: Hmm, yes maybe i can take look at those. Any good good  articles or tutorials of those  anywhere?

Comment: http://devzone.zend.com/1812/using-apc-with-php/

Answer (score 1):

If you're refreshing data every 5 or 10 seconds, and if there are a lot of data, there is no surprise to have performance issues.
Maybe you should **try to use sockets in javascript** to communicate with your server. It's a direct connection.

Comment: This is a good place to start if you're going to go with SSE (Server Sent Events) http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_serversentevents.asp

Comment: What if I get all posts in one request as js array and then just show stuff from the array every 10secs. That way I could avoid this problem?

Comment: Downloading and handling data could take a long time.